# GatsbyJS: Replace part of the server side rendered html

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering

I have a countdown component in my React application, when the countdown has not yet reached the destination date, the `<html>` should have a class `is-counting` otherwise it should have the class `is-complete`.

The implementation is something like this: (Uses the package `react-helmet`)

```
<Countdown toDate={new Date(2019, 5, 14)}>
  {props =>
    props.isComplete ? (
      <Helmet htmlAttributes={{ class: 'is-complete' }} />
    ) : (
      <Helmet htmlAttributes={{ class: 'is-counting' }} />
    )
  }
</Countdown>;
```

So when i run `gatsby build` the server side rendered html has the class `is-counting` like this:

```
<html class="is-counting">…</html>
```

My question is, what's the best way to remove the class that is applied to the `<html>` tag? I need the class to not be applied otherwise my transitions on page load won't work, they should be applied only when the javascript starts to run.

I think the answer lies in this part of the docs: [SSR APIs | GatsbyJS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ssr-apis/#replaceRenderer) but I'm not sure how exactly to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: transition on entire page loading? try to use component lifecycle (Countdown child) - `componentDidMount` to change state - force rerendering or `<Countdown/>` inside some wrapper with similar lifecycle changed conditional rendering.

Comment: Hey @xadm and thanks for your suggestion, I tried that technique shortly after posting the question but I didn't get it to work initially so I thought it wouldn't work. After you mentioned it I tried again and discovered that I simply made a mistake before and the solution was right (the error was writing `this.isClient` instead of `this.state.isClient` :facepalm:)

PS: I now posted an answer following your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, following [@xadm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6124657/xadm) suggestion i got it working, I added `isClient` in the Countdown's state that is initially set to `false`, then in `componentDidMount` I set it to `true` (this lifecycle method is not called when doing ssr) so now I just pass it down as a prop and render the  component conditionally:

```
<Countdown toDate={new Date(2019, 5, 14)}>
  {props =>
    props.isComplete ? (
      {props.isClient && (
        <Helmet htmlAttributes={{ class: 'is-complete' }} />
      )}
    ) : (
      {props.isClient && (
        <Helmet htmlAttributes={{ class: 'is-counting' }} />
      )}
    )
  }
</Countdown>
```

This way the class is only applied client side and my transition on page load works perfectly.

**EDIT**: After a bit of thinking I added the `isClient` state to the root component since:

1. It makes more sense to have it there instead of the Countdown itself
2. It can easily be consumed by other parts of the application if needed